# Rename returned values from SQL Join Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say we have the following query

```
SELECT b.user_name, c.user_name, msg 
FROM user_messages a
JOIN users b ON b.user_id = a.user_from 
JOIN users c ON c.user_id = a.user_to 
WHERE a.user_from = 'ds4EpcrmUt' 
OR a.user_to = 'ds4EpcrmUt'
```

When querying this from NodeJS I will only receive one of the user_names because both returned values have the same name.

Is there some way to rename their returned values like the following?

```
b.user_name = user_from
c.user_name = user_to
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below -

```
SELECT b.user_name as user_from, c.user_name as user_to, msg 
FROM user_messages a
JOIN users b ON b.user_id = a.user_from 
JOIN users c ON c.user_id = a.user_to 
WHERE a.user_from = 'ds4EpcrmUt' 
OR a.user_to = 'ds4EpcrmUt'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast response.

Just got started with joins for my Discord Clone and was falling into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you refere to same column name you need  different column alias name  eg user_name1 and user_name1 or the column name alias  you prefer  :

```
SELECT b.user_name user_name1, c.user_name user_name2, msg 
FROM user_messages a
JOIN users b ON b.user_id = a.user_from 
JOIN users c ON c.user_id = a.user_to 
WHERE a.user_from = 'ds4EpcrmUt' 
OR a.user_to = 'ds4EpcrmUt'
```

Comment: Same as the above response. Thanks for the quick feedback, accepting his answer as it came first.

Comment: @EricE   .  no problem ..  ('try below'  seems not at explanation ..)  anyway you can rate my answer  as useful

Comment: Yeah forsure will! My question was pretty specific and the try below demonstrated how to alias returns from a select. Thanks for the explanation also ! (How do I rate as useful? Just upvote?)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.user_name as user_from, c.user_name as user_to, msg 
FROM user_messages a
JOIN users b ON b.user_id = a.user_from 
JOIN users c ON c.user_id = a.user_to 
WHERE a.user_from = 'ds4EpcrmUt' 
OR a.user_to = 'ds4EpcrmUt'
```

Comment: It's nice when you give small explanation to proposed solution